# Display Typescript verbose typings with no ellipsis

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Until Typescript v2.8 or so, *Typescript* used to show full typings, which were particularly verbose but also extremely convenient to see, for instance, what type *Typescript* was assigning to a generic.

Current versions of *Typescript* display ellipsis everywhere (such as `... 15 more ...`), this way:

```
(method) PipelineAbstract<{ id: string; state: string; isPaid: boolean; updatedAt: number; totalCount: number; totalValue: number; },
        SchemaBuildersInterface<{ id: string; state: string; isPaid: boolean; updatedAt: number; totalCount: number; totalValue: number; },
        ... 15 more ..., never>, {}>.read(query?: {
    id?: string | string[];
    state?: string | string[];
    isPaid?: boolean | boolean[];
    updatedAt?: number | number[];
    totalCount?: number | number[];
    totalValue?: number | number[];
}, options?: {
    skip?: number;
    limit?: number;
    withCount?: boolean;
    sort?: {
        ...;
    };
    _projection?: {
        ...;
    };
}): Promise<...>
```

Ok, it's shorter to display, but almost useless to me. I'd need a complete output, even if it's hard to read, to be able to ensure the libraries parts I write return the expected type and that generic types are inferred as intended.

Is there a flag or something to output the complete type, with no ellipsis? Or was this possibility removed on purpose, performance concerns or something like that?